# How to execute program in child terminal window?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, gnome-terminal

Sorry for not being descriptive in the caption - I dont know how to phrase this.

What I want to do is to run my command line program from bash and in the full terminal window and when i exit it, all output from the program should be cleared. Eg: Functionality of "testdisk". It runs in the full window, but when you exit testdisk, it will return you to the original window.

How can this be done?

Before running app:
[image]

While running app (same terminal window):
[image]

After exiting app:
[image]

Comment: @SeanBright -  gnome-terminal -e ./myapp opens a new terminal window. I want to execute my app inside the same window. Like i said, testdisk or photorec does it like that.

Comment: Is this an irrelevant question? I'm sorry if it is. Can the downvoter please explain why?

Comment: nope. screen ./myapp doesnt work either.

Comment: @SeanBright - i added screenshots to elaborate the question. Could you take a look? Thanks.

Comment: @SeanBright - curses is the way. Thank you. Could you post it as an answer so I can mark you as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example application is using ncurses to draw the window contents. If you require this exact behavior, you will have to modify your application to use ncurses directly for the screen management.